# Arduino and STL

Tags: stl, arduino

I know this has been posted all over the place but I can not find what I need. I have a Arduino project that I must have vector or another way of allocating a dynamic array safely. I am trying to get the "StandardCplusplus" library to compile but I am getting an error

```
'Starting combiner'
"C:\Eclipse\eclipse\arduinoPlugin\tools\arduino\avr-gcc\4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-gcc" -Os -Wl,--gc-sections,--relax -mmcu=atmega2560  -o "D:/Development/MegaTesting/Release/MegaTesting.elf"    ./.ino.cpp.o  ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/algorithm.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/associative_base.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/bitset.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/char_traits.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/complex.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/del_op.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/del_opnt.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/del_opv.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/del_opvnt.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/deque.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/eh_alloc.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/eh_globals.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/exception.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/fstream.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/func_exception.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/iomanip.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/ios.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/iostream.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/istream.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/iterator.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/limits.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/list.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/locale.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/map.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/new_handler.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/new_op.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/new_opnt.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/new_opv.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/new_opvnt.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/numeric.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/ostream.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/queue.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/set.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/sstream.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/stack.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/stdexcept.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/streambuf.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/string.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/support.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/typeinfo.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/utility.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/valarray.cpp.o ./libraries/StandardCplusplus/vector.cpp.o   arduino.ar     "-LD:/Development/MegaTesting/Release" -lm
arduino.ar(new.cpp.o): In function `operator new[](unsigned int)':
C:/Eclipse/eclipse/arduinoPlugin/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.10/cores/arduino/new.cpp:26: multiple definition of `operator new[](unsigned int)'
./libraries/StandardCplusplus/new_opv.cpp.o:C:/Eclipse/eclipse/arduinoPlugin/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.10/libraries/StandardCplusplus/new_opv.cpp:24: first defined here
c:/eclipse/eclipse/arduinoplugin/tools/arduino/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.8.1/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions
arduino.ar(new.cpp.o): In function `operator new(unsigned int)':
C:/Eclipse/eclipse/arduinoPlugin/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.10/cores/arduino/new.cpp:22: multiple definition of `operator delete[](void*)'
makefile:83: recipe for target 'MegaTesting.elf' failed
./libraries/StandardCplusplus/del_opv.cpp.o:C:/Eclipse/eclipse/arduinoPlugin/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.10/libraries/StandardCplusplus/del_opv.cpp:25: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MegaTesting.elf] Error 1

06:23:57 Build Finished (took 21s.666ms)
```

I have searched here and online and there seems to be a bunch of fixes but none of them work. There was some mention of including a pnew.cpp in one of your files but this file is not in the library anywhere.

All my code contains that I am trying to compile is

```
#include "StandardCplusplus.h"
#include "Arduino.h"


void setup(void) {

    Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop(void) {


}
```

There are a couple of versions of this library out there and I have tried the two main forks that I can find and both of them generate this error.

Also I am using Eclipse with the Arduino AVR plugin to compile.

### **Edit**

I thought that commenting out the lines did work until I tried to use a vector. Once I did the StandardCplusplus library got really mad saying that the function new was not defined.

I think that there needs to be something done to the StandardCplusplus library like in new/new_opv delete/delete_opv files? Or is there a better way?

### **Edit - 2**

Alright so I went into the files:

```
StandardCplusplus/new_opv.h
StandardCplusplus/del_opv.h
```

And commented out the bodies for the functions and everything seems to be happy. I did a simple test and everything looks like it is working but now I am concerned that I might of removed something that something else in the library might need, can anyone tell me if my changes will hurt anything?

### **Edit - 3**

Well the last fix didn't work so I tried going to another library all together and I am allot closer. I Downloaded [this STL-AVR library](http://andybrown.me.uk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/) and had to make a minor edit to vector.h now I am having problems with the pnew.cpp file. Looks like the template is calling a "new" function that is now defined in arduino but if I try to comment out this body I get that it is not defined. I am sure this is some sort of order of the includes or missing one can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Those STL like libary versions you have were put together before operator new was added to the Arduino core. Now they are in the core you are getting a multiple definition error.

You can go into your core and comment out the bits causing the multiple definition error.

You can probably just get away with commenting out the function definitions in the .cpp:
`C:/Eclipse/eclipse/arduinoPlugin/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.6.10/cores/arduino/new.cpp`

If you still get the errors, also comment out the function declarations in `new.h`, but you shouldn't need to as multiple declarations are allowed, only definitions must be unique.

Comment: I updated my question can you see if you can shed any light on it?